# PasswordResetConfirmView is not working proeprly?

Tags: python, django

Here I am not using  `PasswordResetView` because i am sending email through my dynamic email configuration so for this I made my own view which generates the token using `PasswordResetTokenGenerator` and it also sends the email to the user. the password reset link in my email looks like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/password-reset/confirm/NQ/5as-b3502199950ff028a6ef/`

But after click in that link it redirect to the `password_reset_confirm` which is good but in this view the `{{form.as_p}}` is not working.It is only displaying the button but before using `auth-views.PasswordresetView` the form was working but now the form is not being passed in the template.

How can i solve this?

urls.py

```
 path('password-reset/',views.send_password_reset_email,name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_done.html'),name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_confirm.html',                                                 success_url=reverse_lazy('password_reset_complete'),),name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

views.py

```
def send_password_reset_email(request):
    form = CustomPasswordResetForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomPasswordResetForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(email__iexact=email)   
            site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = "Password Reset on {} ".format(site.domain)
            message = render_to_string('password_reset_email.html', {
                "user": user,
                'domain': site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token': activation_token.make_token(user)
            })
            config = EmailConfiguration.objects.order_by('-date').first()
            backend = EmailBackend(host=config.email_host, port=config.email_port, username=config.email_host_user,
                                   password=config.email_host_password, use_tls=config.email_use_tls)
            email = EmailMessage(subject=mail_subject, body=message, from_email=config.email_host_user, to=[user.email],
                                 connection=backend)
            email.send()
            return redirect('password_reset_done')

    return render(request, 'password_reset.html',{'form':form})
```

password_reset_email.html

```
{% block reset_link %}
http://{{domain}}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token  %}
{% endblock %}
```

password_reset_confirm.html

```
 <form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
       {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Reset Password</button>
  </form>
```

tokens.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils import six

class TokenGenerate(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.id)+six.text_type(timestamp)+six.text_type(user.is_active)
        )

activation_token=TokenGenerate()
```

Comment: Look at the source of `PasswordResetConfirmView`. It sets the `context['form']` to `None` if `self.validlink == False`. Try printing `{{ title }}` in your template and it'll probably show "Password reset unsuccessful". It looks like it can't find a user with the correct id.

Comment: you shouldn't have `.decode()` at the end of your uid.

Comment: @dirkgroten you are right it says `password reset unsuccessful` i removed the`.decode` also.How can solve this then?

Comment: In your django shell, try: `uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))` and then `User.objects.get(pk=uid)`.

Comment: Also make sure you use the same `token_generator` as the `PasswordResetConfirmView`, I don't see where you're importing `activation_token` from, but it might be the wrong one. Again, look at the Django source code to do the same.

Comment: @dirkgroten i will show you my token_generator

Comment: Well if you write your own toke generator, then obviously when Django checks the token against another generator, this isn't going to work is it? Look at the source code!

Comment: should I have to make my own custom password_confirm_view like i did for password_reset_view @dirkgroten

Comment: @dirkgroten can you help with some code.it would be a great help

Comment: Yes, but you only need to make one very small change: Subclass `PasswordResetConfirmView` and set the `token_generator` to yours.

Comment: @dirkgroten i will try this.Thanks

Comment: and then obviously change the url pattern to use the subclassed view instead of the default one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You subclassed the `PasswordResetTokenGenerator` so you'll also need to use that when verifying the token. Django makes that easy, the `PasswordResetConfirmView` has the `token_generator` as class attribute, so you only need to subclass it to override the token generator it's using:

```
class CustomPasswordResetConfirmView(auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView):
    token_generator = activation_token
```

Then in your url patterns use this view for the `'password-reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/'` path.

Also you need to make sure you encode the `uid` correctly. You can verify you did it correctly by checking in your django shell:

```
uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
User.objects.get(pk=uid)
```

which should return the user.

Note that your `_make_hash_value` method is not secure: It's always going to generate the same hash during the one day that the timestamp remains valid. So it can be re-used multiple times even after the user changed the password and anyone with access to the email will be able to reset the password again. That's why the original `_make_hash_value` of Django's generator uses the password, so after it's changed, it cannot be used again.

Worse, I can make the token for any of your users, and reset their password this way, because I don't need to know anything but their id, which is an integer, so I can just try until I hit an id that exists in your db.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201249/discussion-on-answer-by-dirkgroten-passwordresetconfirmview-is-not-working-proep).

Comment: Error: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. Please help me out

Comment: @Shoaib21 That error means you're passing an argument into the initialiser of a class to instantiate it that isn't supposed to be there. Since you're not showing us any context for your error (we don't know which class's __init__() method is raising the error), it's impossible to tell. The whole error trace would help. But you should submit that as a new question.